# Usando uma prop de um objeto como key em outro objeto em TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou tentando exportar um objeto com meus tipos válidos e criar um type baseado nisso. Até aí tudo bem, o problema é a interface que espera uma string mas não está aceitando a prop do objeto (que é uma string) como válida.

```js
export const SortValues = {
  NEWER: 'NEWER',
  OLDER: 'OLDER',
  NAME_ASC: 'NAME_ASC',
  NAME_DESC: 'NAME_DESC',
}

interface Option<T = string> {
  key: T;
  value: string;
}

type SortValuesType = keyof typeof SortValues;

// type SortValuesType = 'NEWER' | 'OLDER' | 'NAME_ASC' | 'NAME_DESC'; // Não funciona também.

export const options: Array<Option<SortValuesType>> = [
  { key: SortValues.NEWER, value: 'Mais novos' },
  { key: SortValues.OLDER, value: 'Mais antigos' },
  { key: SortValues.NAME_ASC, value: 'A - Z' },
  { key: SortValues.NAME_DESC, value: 'Z - A' },
];
```

Estou recebendo o erro `"Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"NEWER" | "OLDER" | "NAME_ASC" | "NAME_DESC"'."` na propriedade key das options.

Funciona se eu declarar SortValues como um enum, portém isso está me causando problemas em outros lugares, então eu queria mesmo exportar as opções válidas como um objeto.

Aqui está um snippet com o código em questão.
https://codesandbox.io/s/fqide

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/418963/edit) e traduza a pergunta.

Comment: @LuizAugusto Feito, vacilei na hora de postar. Não reparei que estava no pt-br. Mal aê.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está declarando `SortValues` como objeto em linha e está tentando utilizar suas propriedades como se fossem tipos.

Eu acho que o que você está procurando é uma enumeração, documentada [aqui](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#union-enums-and-enum-member-types) e [aqui](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#enum-member-types).

Na documentação está escrito:

> ...quando todos os membros de uma enumeração têm valores literais, uma
>   semântica especial é aplicada.
>
> A primeira é que os membros da enum também se tornam tipos! Por
>   exemplo, podemos dizer que determinados membros podem ter apenas o
>   valor de um membro enum...

Que ao meu ver se encaixa com que está tentando fazer.

```
// Não é mais um objeto agora é uma enumeração
export enum SortValues {
  NEWER = 'NEWER',
  OLDER = 'OLDER',
  NAME_ASC ='NAME_ASC',
  NAME_DESC = 'NAME_DESC',
}

// A chave teve o tipo adequado para enumeração
interface Option<T = SortValues> {
  key: T;
  value: string;
}

type SortValuesType = keyof typeof SortValues;


//Agora as chaves podem ser valoradas de acordo com os membros da enumeração SortValues
export const options: Array<Option<SortValuesType>> = [
  { key: SortValues.NEWER  , value: 'Mais novos' },
  { key: SortValues.OLDER, value: 'Mais antigos' },
  { key: SortValues.NAME_ASC, value: 'A - Z' },
  { key: SortValues.NAME_DESC, value: 'Z - A' },
];
```

---

**PS:** Não sei exatamente o que está fazendo mas acho que esse fragmento:

```
type SortValuesType = keyof typeof SortValues;

export const options: Array<Option<SortValuesType>> = [
  { key: SortValues.NEWER  , value: 'Mais novos' },
  { key: SortValues.OLDER, value: 'Mais antigos' },
  { key: SortValues.NAME_ASC, value: 'A - Z' },
  { key: SortValues.NAME_DESC, value: 'Z - A' },
];
```

pode ser simplificado:

```
//type SortValuesType = keyof typeof SortValues;

export const options: Array<Option> = [
  { key: SortValues.NEWER  , value: 'Mais novos' },
  { key: SortValues.OLDER, value: 'Mais antigos' },
  { key: SortValues.NAME_ASC, value: 'A - Z' },
  { key: SortValues.NAME_DESC, value: 'Z - A' },
];
```